# Angular: Input with model binding acts on keypress, only when there's no controller

Tags: binding, angularjs, keypress

Angular newb here, thoughts appreciated...

Say I want an input field to control the window title as you type. A field with a model binding and no associated controller acts on keypress, as intended. However, there has to be a bit more logic to it -- default value  before any user input, also used if the input is blanked.

Adding a controller bound to enclosing elements gives a place for that logic, but the change-on-keypress behavior is gone. I'm sure it's possible to recreate it by hand or with ui, but since it's inherently there without the controller, I'm wondering if I'm missing the simple clean way.

Simple version, acts on keypress, but with no smarts:

```
<title ng-bind-template="{{windowTitle}}">Default Title (not seen)</title>
<input ng-model="windowTitle" type="text">
```

Putting controller bindings on the head (for the title) and a containing div (for the input), and setting a default $scope.windowTitle inside the controller function does use that default value, but it breaks the auto-update.

I know in real life you'd want a real model, but what I'm really trying to understand is these two ways angular appears to work. I haven't found anything specifically describing two different implicit input binding behaviors, but I haven't been through all the docs yet.

How should I be thinking about this?

---

**Edit:** It's not the window title or default value per se that I'm interested in. I'm trying to understand this:

- When there's no controller on either the field or the title, typing in the field changes the window title immediately, on keypress. The title is directly linked to the field value, with no other angular hookup.
- With controller bindings around the title and the field, typing in the field has no effect on the title.

What I've since realized (I think) is that ng-controller bindings create a new instance of the controller each time. Here's the non-working code I didn't show before:

```
<title ng-controller="TitleCtrl" ng-bind-template="{{windowTitle || 'Foo'}}">Foo</title>
...
<label ng-controller="TitleCtrl">
    <input ng-model="windowTitle" type="text">
    {{windowTitle}}
</label>
```

The value set by the model binding to the field is shown correctly within that instance of that controller, and updates on keypress, as before. But since those two controller instances are separate, the binding to the title works but the data it points to isn't bound to the field.

Isn't that right? The reason it works with no controllers is that that makes the value global, so the title binding sees the value set by the field binding.

So what's the canonical way to reference data from some other area? Create a service?

I realize that this is basic angular stuff, just getting started here, so thanks!

---

**Edit 2**
On reflection, I've come to seriously disrespect this whole question, even though I wrote it.

It's based on way-too-early poor understanding of the Angular application model. I had worked through only part of the official tutorials, and jumped ahead to removing all the js from a not big but not totally trivial existing app, and exploring what Angular could to in that context.

I got some very quick bang for the buck, getting several pieces of functionality working with very little code, and simple, clear markup, felt good. But I really had short-circuited internalizing the Angular way of thinking, and my quick and dirty no-architecture approach broke down when different parts of the page needed to coordinate with each other, as in this question.

I've postponed that project while I go back to tutorials and other learning. If other folks think this question should be deleted, I'd add my vote. Or maybe it's a useful on some level, ignorant though it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are multiple ways to achieve the behavior you want without using an explicit controller and model, you could:

```
<title ng-bind-template="{{windowTitle && windowTitle || 'default'}}"></title>
```

Or in a more simple way:

```
<title>{{windowTitle && windowTitle || 'default' }}</title>
```

In both cases, we're using the conditional expression:

```
(condition) && (answer if true) || (answer if false)
```

You should however strive to remove logic from the templates.

Comment: just use <title>{{windowTitle||'Default'}}</title> it's the same thing

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, understood. I didn't express the part of this I was trying to get at well, now edited.

Comment: Small thing: The reason for ng-bind-template vs the raw expression is to keep the unprocessed code from flashing in the window title before angular does its thing.